# When we run coreference resolution program it will throw an error how can i solve?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am new to coreference resolution when we run the program it will throw an error i m very confused to resolve please help me with it

```
    Annotation document = new Annotation("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He is the president. Obama was elected in 2008.");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,coref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("coref chains");
    for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
      System.out.println("\t" + cc);
    }
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("---");
      System.out.println("mentions");
      for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println("\t" + m);
       }
```

The error occured is mentioned below

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.splitOnChar(StringUtils.java:537)
at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Dictionaries.loadGenderNumber(Dictionaries.java:405)
at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Dictionaries.<init>(Dictionaries.java:676)
at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Dictionaries.<init>(Dictionaries.java:576)
at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefSystem.<init>(CorefSystem.java:32)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CorefAnnotator.<init>(CorefAnnotator.java:66)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.coref(AnnotatorImplementations.java:196)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$53(StanfordCoreNLP.java:555)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$24/544724190.apply(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$69(StanfordCoreNLP.java:625)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$37/1673605040.get(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)
at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:495)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:201)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:194)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:181)
at test.test.main(test.java:17)
```

Comment: please help me to solve the problem i am new to this i don't know how to solvethe issue

Comment: respond to the problem it is the main important part of my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your Java process with more memory.  On the command line you typically do this with `java -Xmx5g ...`.  I am not sure specifically how much memory you should use for your code, but I think something around `4g` should be fine.  It's possible less will work as well.

Comment: The program will run fine the output i got will be 'coref chains
 CHAIN3-["Barack Obama" in sentence 1, "He" in sentence 2, "Obama" in sentence 3]
---
mentions
 Barack Obama
 Hawaii
---
mentions
 the president
 He
---
mentions
 Obama
 2008'

Comment: But i Try another example it will not work fine " Annotation document = new Annotation("vishnu is a bad boy.He loves cricket.Ms is his favorite player");"  output that i got will be coref chains
 CHAIN3-["vishnu" in sentence 1, "his" in sentence 1]
---
mentions
 vishnu
 a bad boy.He loves cricket.Ms is his favorite player
 cricket. --not matching properly @StanfordNLPHelp